# React - changing values in server is not reflected in DOM immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the client side, I have a modal in my HomeComponent where I can choose an element. Then, what I want is to render that element inside the same HomeComponent (in the productosEnVenta function). The element that I choose in the modal is then POST in the server through a fetch in my ActionCreators, and in the HomeComponent I show the elements that were posted before. My problem is that when I select the element from the modal, the program gets an error because it takes the element that I just selected as undefined, but when I reload the browser, the element is shown as normal. I believe that this has something to do with the life cycle of the component, but I don't know if I have to use a componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate to solve this. I hope somebody can help me.

Here is the code:

```
function productosEnVenta(postVenta, preparado, productos, restarCant, deleteCero) {
  if (preparado.length > 0){
    return(
      <div>
        {preparado.map((receta) => {
          const producto = productos.filter((producto) => producto._id === receta.productoId._id)[0]
          return(
            <div key={receta._id}>
                <Card>
                  <CardImg src={baseUrl + producto.image} /> //the error is shown here. It says it can't read .image of undefined

                  <CardTitle>{producto.name}</CardTitle>
                </Card>              
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
  else {
    return(
      <div><h4>No hay productos preparados</h4></div>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {

  render(){
    const ModalElegirReceta = ({putIngrediente, productos, inventario}) => {
      const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
      const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

      function restarIngrediente(ingrediente){
        for (var elem of ingrediente){
          var restar = elem.gramos;
          var enInventario = inventario.filter((inven) => inven.ingrediente === elem.ingrediente)[0];
          console.log('en inventario: ', enInventario);
          var restante = enInventario.disponible - restar;
          putIngrediente(enInventario._id, enInventario.ingrediente, enInventario.costo, restante, enInventario.conversiones);
        }
      }

      return(
        <div>
          <Button onClick={toggle}>Elegir Receta</Button>
          <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Elegir Receta</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Form>
                {productos.map((receta) => {

                  return(
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-3" key={receta._id}>
                          <Card onClick={() => {this.props.postPreparado(receta._id, receta.porciones, receta.precio); restarIngrediente(receta.ingredientes)}}>
                            <CardImg src={baseUrl + receta.image} />
                            <CardTitle>{receta.name}</CardTitle>
                          </Card>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </Form>
            </ModalBody>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }



    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row row-content">
          <div className="col-12">
          {productosEnVenta(this.props.postVenta, this.props.preparado.preparado, this.props.productos, this.props.putRestarPreparado, this.props.deleteCero)}
          </div>
          <div className="col-12 justify-content-center">
            <ModalElegirReceta putIngrediente = {this.props.putIngrediente} 
                               productos = {this.props.productos} 
                               inventario = {this.props.inventario}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering to guard against errors.

Like with `producto.image`, if you expect `producto` might be undefined at some point, you can edit your function to return this instead:

```
return producto && (
            <div key={receta._id}>
                <Card>
                  <CardImg src={baseUrl + producto.image} /> //the error is shown here. It says it can't read .image of undefined

                  <CardTitle>{producto.name}</CardTitle>
                </Card>              
            </div>
          );
```

There may be more issues with your data flow but this will prevent your app from crashing.

Comment: Yes, it did prevent my app from crashing, thank you! But I still have the problem that it doesn't render in the DOM the selected element, but when I refresh the page now it is shown. I have in another component all the "fetches" to obtain all the data, and they don't update when I do this action.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more code, but that function expression (`ModalElegirReceta`) inside of the render should not be like that. 

Try moving the useState out of the render.As well make sure you are setting something in state or props when you receive your api response, that's the only way your component render function will run. Otherwise your api call would be resolving silently.

I recommend using a `debugger` statement to see what exactly your application is doing, or not doing. It should give you some clue to what's missing.